# SonarQube 5.6 LDAP (FreeIPA) authenticated users have no groups

Tags: authentication, ldap, sonarqube, freeipa

I saw some posts on stackoverflow, like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086192/ldap-authenticated-user-gets-deleted-from-the-group-created-in-sonar-for-every-f) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601224/sonarqube-5-6-ldap-2-0-failing-to-authenticate), but problem still exists. I updated sonarqube from 5.3 to 5.6. Here's example of my config:

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.security.savePassword=false
sonar.security.localUsers=admin
ldap.authentication=simple
ldap.url=ldap://ipa.company.com
ldap.bindDn=uid=ldap_search,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=company,dc=com
ldap.bindPassword=*************

ldap.user.baseDn=cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=company,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail

ldap.group.baseDn=cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=company,dc=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))
ldap.group.idAttribute=cn
```

The problem is in authentication. If i create local user, then i can't authenticate using same LDAP (FreeIPA) account, according to [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) docs (*Local users* block). If i authenticate first time with FreeIPA account i see newly created sonar user, but it has no groups (*sonar-users* for example, but he is actually a member of *sonar-users* in FreeIPA groups)

Here's example of test account in sonarqube - http://joxi.ru/zAN46EXcb9gem9, and test account in FreeIPA - http://joxi.ru/VrwnzgDcBeGxAX. 
Even, when i login with admin and add groups to test user, they disappear after next login.

Here's example from mysql *sonar.users* db:

```
| id | login                    | updated_at    | external_identity        | external_identity_provider | user_local |
| 32 | test                     | 1494580874688 | test                     | sonarqube                  |          0 |
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of weeks i finally found right solution! I realized that problem was in group synchronization, so right config for group sync must looks like next one for your FreeIPA configuration:

```
ldap.group.baseDn=cn=groups,cn=compat,dc=company,dc=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(memberUid={uid}))
ldap.group.idAttribute=cn
```

Difference is in cn=groups,**cn=compat**,dc=company,dc=com.
You can't use `memberUid` filter with `cn=accounts`.